Update statement in hadoop ecosystem using hive (WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred)
I am having trouble with running a simple update statement.
The query i am excecuting is the follow
NSERT INTO data_source_metadata VALUES (
    'source1',                        
    'User Information',                
    'CSV',                            
    'Structured',                      
    '1000',                           
    'Batch',                          
    '10MB',                           
    'High',                           
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,                
    ARRAY('user', 'information'),     
    ARRAY(),  
    '/user/hdfs/data_sources/source1'       
);

I found the logs of this excecution and this is what i got
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2 (file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-4.0.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Oct 29, 2024 3:14:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Oct 29, 2024 3:14:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Oct 29, 2024 3:14:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
Oct 29, 2024 3:14:34 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.4 05/24/2017 03:20 PM'
Oct 29, 2024 3:14:34 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Oct 29, 2024 3:14:35 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Oct 29, 2024 3:14:35 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I am currently using java version 11
I am guessing there is something to do with some configurations in the ecosystem? Or the schmea of my database? I store it as orc so i can excetute insert and update statements..
CREATE TABLE data_source_metadata (
    source_id STRING,
    source_name STRING,
    variety_type STRING,
    data_type STRING,
    value STRING,
    velocity STRING,
    volume STRING,
    veracity STRING,
    last_update TIMESTAMP,
    keywords ARRAY<STRING>,
    hdfs_path STRING
) STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ('transactional'='true');

